# Git text invisible

Tags: git, text, invisible

I have problems with using my GIT. Everything works fine when running the CMD and the '$' shows up and my text shows up. But when i go to my git log my text suddenly dissapears, It's just a ':' and i can type commands but not see them.

When i go out from the git log the text still is not appearing. I have a picture in my link below.

If i type CTRL+C 2 times i can see the '$' sign but the text is still gone.

[Git-text-dissapear-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ6nx.png)

Comment: Well, the picture you have linked just show the correct `git log` behavior. You just need to hit the q on your keyboard to quit the pager that `git log` is using to output the info. I don't understand the problem of the gone text, did you try to scroll up?

Comment: When i type in commands i can't see what i'm typing after visiting the git log. Even if i press Q i can see the $ sign but still i can't see my text when i'm typing even though i could see it before i visited the log.

Comment: I think this is not a git problem. This seems to be a problem with your command prompt or your configuration.

Comment: It is a bug in bash (not git) on Windows (MINGW64) with hitting Ctrl-C while in the pager. Using `q` as suggested exits the pager nicely and characters typed will be echoed normally.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I had this problem after exiting `git log` in windows git bash today, i fixed it by resetting the terminal using `reset`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! While the accepted answer provides a lot of info, it doesn't explain that on Windows, echoing to the screen in bash is destructed by `less`. Using `reset` (typing it, even though you won't see it) fixes this.

Comment: confirmed, this is definitely the answer! just had this exact issue and solved easily with reset

Answer (score 10):

To exit the git log interface you must type `:q`.

Using <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to exit `less` or another pager, will lead to the characters being swallowed (that is: not echoed to the screen). Using `q` will exit it nicely and the bash prompt will echo what you type.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. If you use `q` instead of `Ctrl-C`, your prompt echoes the characters normally. Using `Ctrl-C` will swallow any character and only `reset`  gets them back.

Comment: I think this should be the choosen as the most accurate answer

Answer (score 4):

`git log` uses your configured pager to display one screen of information at a time.

The default pager on Unix-based systems nowadays is `less` and this is probably also the pager on your system. I guess you are using Git Bash which is just a bunch of Linux programs ported to work on Windows.

`less` displays a screen of information and on the last line of the terminal window it displays the `:` prompt, waiting for a command. It has several commands you can learn about if you press `h` at the prompt.

The most used `less` commands are:

- `f` or `<space>` to display the next screen (`f` comes from "Forward");
- `b` to display the previous screen (`b` comes from "Backward");
- `/` followed by a regular expression and `enter` to search for matching substrings in the input data, starting with the displayed screen (search forward);
- `?` followed by a regular expression and `enter` to search backward;
- `h` to display the help (the list of commands);
- `q` to quit.

Most commands have two or more keys assigned. I listed above only on key which is also the easiest to type.

You can use the `less` commands when you read its help (it is more than one screen).

> If i type CTRL+C 2 times i can see the '$' sign but the text is still gone.

On quit, `less` restores the screen in the status it found it when it started.

In order to use a different pager program (for all Git commands that require one) you can set it in the Git config:

```
git config core.pager /bin/more
```

Replace `/bin/more` in the command above with the full path of you favorite pager program.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I can't apply it! Would you kindly clarify what you mean by "favorite pager program"? put an example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem after using the `$ git log` command

I have fixed this after using a `reset` command in the CLI, things are back to normal.

Note: Just `reset` the Git bash even though if you can't see the text the command will execute anyways.